# send notification to a particular user with notification hub - Azure and GCM

Tags: notifications, google-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I am a software developer in Xamarin - Android, I want to create notification messages. For this purpose I use Azure notification hub, combined with Google's service - Google Cloud Messaging (GCM).

My problem comes when I want to send notification to a particular user. I realized that I need to use the "TAGS" When I compose a new user to the system (Uniqe TAG)

Indeed, it works great, but when the user logged off his account, and then connect to another one (with another TAGS) - the TAGS of his old account are kept in a certain time, and he continues to receive personal messages from the previous account!!!!

Does anyone know what can be done about it?

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This is actually [an issue a lot of people/apps have on iOS and Android](https://www.google.com/search?q=push%20notification%20logged%20out&rct=j).

What you should do is:

- Register your app at your Azure Notification Hub (ANH) on first start and [reregister at every app start, to keep registration in sync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530747.aspx)
- If a user logs in, update the registration with an additional tag for this user (e.g. "user:XY")

  - Sending notifications to that user tag will of course result in notifications on all devices the user is logged in on
- **If a user logs out, update the registration without the user tag (omit the user tag, so the registration doesn't have user tag anymore afterwards)**

  - The registration will be updated immediately on ANH and sending notifications to the user (tag) will not result in notifications on that specific client

If the user can logout on your app without internet connection, you won't be able to update the registration of course and you will still have the problem of getting notifications for a logged out user. But as soon as another user logs in, the registration should get updated with the new user tag and everything should be fine again...

What you shouldn't do:

- [*"Developers should never unregister the client app as a mechanism for logout or for switching between users..."*](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration)